# How do I transfer the files from my Coral Dev Board to the SD card/ PC for training?

Tags: google-coral

I have connected my coral device to my Windows laptop running UBUNTU 20.04
1)When I try to " scp file.tar.gz @: /home/, I get an error stating
"ssh: connection to port 22: lost connection and sometimes refused connection".
I tried to put my Mendel boards IP and host username, then it asked me for my password but then denied permission.

2)Now I wanted to try it using the SD card. So I formatted the SD card in ext4 format and mounted it using " sudo mount /dev/mmcblk1 /mnt. And I can access contents of the SD card.

Now my question is- how do I transfer contents(files and pics) from SD to the Coral board and vice-versa?

I'd appreciate a detailed answer please. If you know the answer to query 1) please mention or if you know the answer to both pls try to help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. There are 2 ways to do this:

- You can use `mdt push` or `mdt pull` to move file from and to the dev board.
  Refer to this doc: https://coral.ai/docs/dev-board/mdt/#mdt-commands
- mdt should already creates a public key o n your host machine in `~/.config/mdt/keys/mdt.key`, you can try ssh/scp using that key

```
ssh -i ~/.config/mdt/keys/mdt.key mendel@ip-addr
```

If that doesn't works, you can also make your own key:

```
ssh-keygen
```

Then copy your public key on to the dev board's `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` and everything should works as normal ssh :)

2. If you already mounted the sdcard, they it is as easy as copying or moving right?

```
cp /mnt/file-you-want /home/mendel/where-you-want
```

Comment: Thank you, will give it a shot.

Comment: Okay so I was able to transfer the file to my SD card. But after I remove the SD card from the board and plug it in the PC, I don't see anything appear in my PC. The Card doesn't seem to connect or maybe I don't know how to access it. But when I was on the Board and I check the /mnt directory I see the file I transferred. How do I access the files through my laptop now? I need to train the model and transfer the files back to the dev board. thanks